# ASP.Net MVC 5 Google Authentication with Scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get ASP.Net MVC 5 Google OAuth2 authentication working correctly.

When I set pass in a GoogleOauth2AuthenticationOptions without any scope, then I'm able to log in successfully.

```
var googlePlusOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = googleClientId,
    ClientSecret = googleClientSecret,
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:googleplus:accesstoken", ctx.AccessToken));
        }
    },
};

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googlePlusOptions);
```

Then this call will return an ExternalLoginInfo object with all the properties set

```
ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

When I **add any scope** though, then I don't get any login info returned. It's just null.

```
var googlePlusOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = googleClientId,
    ClientSecret = googleClientSecret,
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:googleplus:accesstoken", ctx.AccessToken));
        }
    },
};

googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube);

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googlePlusOptions);
```

Then the call to get external info just **returns null**.

```
ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

In the Google dev console, I have the following APIs turned on..

- Analytics API
- BigQuery API
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Google+ API
- Google+ Domains API
- Identity Toolkit API
- YouTube Analytics API
- YouTube Data API v3

Something about adding scope to the options is breaking GetExternalLoginInfoAsync.

Answer (score 12):

*If anyone's still having trouble with this with the latest Microsoft
   OWIN middleware (3.0.0+)...*

---

I noticed from Fiddler that by default, the following scope is sent to accounts.google.com:

```
scope=openid%20profile%20email
```

If you add your own scope(s) via GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add(...), then the scope becomes:

```
scope=YOUR_SCOPES_ONLY
```

Therefore, you need to add the default scopes too (or at least, this fixed the issue for me):

```
var googlePlusOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions {
    ...
};

// default scopes
googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("email");

// additional scope(s)
googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
```

Answer (score 9):

So, I figured this out, with a lot of help from http://www.beabigrockstar.com/blog/google-oauth-sign-asp-net-identity. It turns out that the built in Google authentication provider for MVC is openId only. That's why adding a scope broke it. Using Fiddler, I was able to see the GET request to accounts.google.com, which included "scope=openid" in the querystring.

By switching to the GooglePlusOAuth2 provider in the link above, or on Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.GooglePlus and using the provider name of "GooglePlus", I was able to succesfully add the scopes and still get back the login info from GetExternalLoginInfoAsync.

Answer (score 2):

The changes Google has made to their auth mechanisms have been [reflected in version 3.0.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx) of Microsoft Owin middleware. As you have identified correctly, one of the changes have been moving the OAuth endpoint to Google+ (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me).
So, the key is to:

1. upgrade the OWIN middleware to version 3.0.0
2. enable Google+ API for your app in Google Developers Console

Comment: Here's the nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/